# Error with 'Alter Table' Command SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am having a frustrating problem when I try to add a new column in an existing table named `Group`on the SQL Server.

My command is the following:

```
ALTER TABLE Group
ADD languageID INT
```

The error I get is the following:

> Incorrect syntax near 'Group'. Expecting '.', ID, or QUOTED_ID

Any idea why is this happening ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Group is reserved word. put it into brackets, like next

```
ALTER TABLE [Group]
ADD languageID INT
```

Comment: @dimmik, welcome bro, plz flag this answer as accepted one.

Comment: i will i just need to wait a few minutes

Answer (score 2):

Since `GROUP` is a key word, you should not use it for Object names. If possible rename your table name to another name.

However try like below

```
ALTER TABLE [Group] ADD languageID INT
```

Answer (score 1):

Group is a keyword in SQL Server. Please try this:

```
ALTER TABLE [Group]
ADD languageID INT
```

Answer (score 1):

Group is a sql reserved keyword. So it is giving syntax error as it is referring to that keyword.
use this

```
ALTER TABLE [Group]
ADD languageID INT
```

Or you can create different table with different name like Group1

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE [Group]
ADD languageID INT
```